# Getting function to return prime numbers only in R

Tags: r

Hi guys I have this function which prints the factors of number entered by the user, I want to return only the prime numbers of the factors printed, how can I do this in R?

```
print_factors <- function(k) {
  for(i in 1:k) {
    if((k %% i) == 0) {
      print(i)
      
    }
  }
}
```

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Did you mean "how can I do this in Ruby"?

Comment: Yes, like how can I get the function to return the factors of k that are also prime numbers...It is R

Comment: How large can `k` be? Do we need to care about efficiency? For large `k` it might be best to base the solution on an existing (pre-computed) list of prime numbers.

Comment: No we dont care about efficiency...it has to be a function that I code myself

Comment: In Ruby: `require 'prime'; Prime.prime_division(24) #=> [[2, 3], [3, 1]]`. This means that `2**3 * 3**1 => 8*3 => 24`, so `24` has primes `2` and `3`. All factors of `24` can be easily generated from this information. Similarly, `Prime.prime_division(55125) #=> [[3, 2], [5, 3], [7, 2]]`, meaning `3**2 * 5**3 * 7**2 #=> 55125`. See [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division).

Comment: Are you looking for an **algorithm**, or do you already have an algorithm in your mind, and just struggle with the **implementation** in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

```
#check according to the definition of a prime number
is.prime <- function(x) all(x %% (2:(x - 1)) != 0)

print_factors <- function(k) {
  for(i in 1:k) {
    if((k %% i) == 0 && is.prime(i)) {
      print(i)
      
    }
  }
}

print_factors(210)
#[1] 3
#[1] 5
#[1] 7
```

PS: Your teacher will recognize that you have not coded this yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much :) , do you know how I can print them in a list instead of line by line?